# How do I differentiate between the downloaded client and the online client

Tags: office365

I want to do something super basic in "Office 365", which I consider to be a cloud based solution in contrast to the old MSWord, MSExcel, and ExchangeServer/OutlookClient systems in days of old.

But whenever I google tutorials from Microsoft on simple tasks, they are all done in the perspective of the downloaded and installed software.  How useless is that?  Nearly everything I want to do which seems super basic says to select the "Developer Tab", which doesn't exist.

My current quandry is the simple task of creating a Business Card in Office365.  But surprise! The tutorials say to go to a particular part of the ribbon which doesn't exist in Outlook Online.

**The Question** How can I google for simple things like, "How to create a Business Card in Outlook", but only find results related to the cloud-based Office365?  All my searches return tutorials in the installed software.

Comment: On Microsoft's website, any Office feature that is documented, indicates which versions of Office has the feature.  Can you be more specific?  An example of something that isn't documented clearly?

Answer (score 1):

Office Online is free for Word, Excel, OneNote, and PowerPoint documents in web browser. there are some differences in feature between the Office online and Office desktop apps.

You can review those articles to learn it: [Office for the web Service Description](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-online-service-description/office-online-service-description), [Differences between using a document in the browser and in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/differences-between-using-a-document-in-the-browser-and-in-word-3e863ce3-e82c-4211-8f97-5b33c36c55f8), and [Differences between using a workbook in the browser and in Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-the-browser-and-in-excel-f0dc28ed-b85d-4e1d-be6d-5878005db3b6).

> My current quandry is the simple task of creating a Business Card in Office365. But surprise! The tutorials say to go to a particular part of the ribbon which doesn't exist in Outlook Online.

I tested it in my outlook online and no luck. Maybe this is a client feature which means we need to use the Outlook client for it.

Review [Create and share contacts as Electronic Business Cards](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-and-share-contacts-as-electronic-business-cards-da84e482-47f5-4be0-ae75-d31ac04f9e04)
[image]

Comment: Bella, that is great information.  Regarding the red box image you posted, do you know what that would say if it were also possible in the online version?  You point out that those are the versions that article applies to, but I see "Outlook 2019", which I would consider the desktop client, and I see "Outlook for Office 365", which I would consider the web client.  Am I wrong?  What would it say if it were applicable to the Web Client?

Comment: @Suamere, Both Outlook 2019 and Outlook 365 are client desktop version. They are just different version. You can refer to the Word Online, it says "word for the web"